# How to combine two regex?

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have these two regex:

1. `id=123456`
2. `discography=True`

How can I check if they both matches the regex, without knowing the order of these strings in the input beforehand?

Comment: You *could* combine them, but why not simply match one, then match the other?

Comment: Your question is vague; could you edit it to precise the regex(es) you have in mind?  Also, you can't have "a regex matching a regex", so I suppose your first sentence could be rephrased to "I have these two input strings"?

Comment: I'm using a module that can work with one regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use two [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?=.*id=123456)(?=.*discography=True)
```

From the beginning of the string (`^`) we first look for `id=123456` anywhere (due to the `.*`). But the lookahead doesn't actually consume anything, so once the pattern was found, the engine jumps back to where it started (beginning of the string) and starts on the second pattern.

As pointed out by eyquem, if there are line breaks in your string, `.*` cannot go past them, unless you use the option `re.S` (or `re.DOTALL` - that's just an alias).

However, this looks like you are trying to parse the query string of a URL. Maybe you should have a look at [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html).

Comment: This sure looks like a querystring, but it's not :)

Comment: @m.buettner A regex based on the pattern ``^(?=.*id=123456)(?=.*discography=True)`` doesn't match the string ``'abcde \n fghi id=123456 discography=True jklmn'``

Comment: @eyquem true, if there are line breaks, you need `re.S`. good point

Comment: @m.buettner Or ``re.MULTILINE`` if the implied idea of the OP is to test the presence of the two parts inside lines, not inside the whole text.

Comment: @eyquem well yeah, but that seems a bit far fetched from the question, doesn't it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming r1 and r2 are well-formed regexps, you could do:

```
re.compile("(?=%s)%s" % (r1, r2))
```

Comment: That will look at both patterns at the same position, which is impossible.

Comment: How is that impossible? That's what it does.

Comment: by "impossible" I mean, it can never match

Comment: Only if r1 and r2 are written so that the regexps would never both match. But plenty of regexps are not written that way. For example, suppose r1 = r'(a|b)' and r2 = r'b*c'. Or as above, assume that r1 = r'.*id=123456', and r2 = r'.*discography=True'

Comment: Yes, but how is the OP supposed to know from your answer that (s)he has to include `.*` into the patterns?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for independent checks for your first and second regex, it should work by checking if your regexes have results.

```
import re
results1 = re.search("id=([0-9]+)", "id=123456")
results2 = re.search("discography=(True|False)", "discography=True")
if results1 != None and results2 != None:
    print "Both matched"
```